# Getting Error while defining mongo:repositories

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I get this error when I run my Junit test

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from class path resource [mongo-test-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 89; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mongo:repository'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository":include-filter, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository":exclude-filter}' is expected.
```

Here is my relevant  spring config file

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongoConnection" host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="gov.ic.isso.ce.data">
    <mongo:repository id="dictionaryService" mongo-template-ref="dictionaryTemplate" />
</mongo:repositories>
```

Here are my dependencies defined in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Hello allthenutsandbolts,

it seams you have bad xml format, please, provide complete xml so we can analyse.


Regards,
Moacy

Comment: I figured it out, the schema has changed and you have to have  <repository:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*ProductRepository" />
        <repository:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*CurrencyRepository" />

Comment: Reply with answer on answer window.